# How to send frame like RealTerm via USB using c#

Tags: c#, dataframe, usb

Good morning,

I would like to ask how to send data frame via Usb like software RealTerm sending to the microprocesor to changing ip. I have commands in RealTerm software but I need to something like that using C#. This is small additive to some another software. I am interesting in data frame structure and how that thing looks. I can't find that.

I have the Real Therm i started creating another software but i cant find data frame structure via usb

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: the commands that i send by real term are +++, AT+SRVIP=192.168.2.159, AT+RST. But i don't know how to send this commands via usb Frame